# Answered own question about rooting a device, now what?

Tags: discussion, recommendation, best-practices

I was answering the question [Do I root to my model, or my version number?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49919/16265) where the user need to root a particular device and I assumed that it miss-phrased the title.

After 3 hours preparing the answer and rooting the device on my end, I've posted the answer and re-read the OP question and commend, where it reads:

> I'm currently using a Samsung Galaxy Attain, but if possible, I was hoping to find out if there was an answer that isn't phone-specific, or if it's case-by-case. – Coronus 1 hour ago

Given that my answer wasn't adequate to the question, I've deleted it and created a Q&A for this situation *"[How to root the Galaxy Attain 4G (SCH-R920) on MetroPCS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49925/16265)"*.

Now I don't know what's the correct "next step", should I mark my answer as the correct one and move on or wait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You "asked" that second question, and offered the solution as an answer. As that solution worked for you, you should accept that answer. If in the future another answer shows up which seems more suitable, you can still accept that (and thus un-accept yours). So I'd go ahead :)